# Google login using in app web-view in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, google-oauth, google-signin

I have implemented a web-view in **react-native** which

- opens up website in web view let say (example.com)
- shows up a google login button on (example.com/login)

I am trying to login via web-view and open whole website in web-view inside app

```
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <WebView
      source={{
        uri: "https://example.com"
      }}
      style={{flex: 1}}
    />
  </View>
```

When I tried to click on google login button, I get this error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have to privide user agent [User agent](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#useragent)  in my case

```
<WebView
userAgent={DeviceInfo.getUserAgent() + " - MYAPPNAME - android "}   
ref={"WEBVIEW"}
automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
source={{uri: this.state.url}} />
```

Comment: I added exactly this `          userAgent={DeviceInfo.getUserAgent()}   `, but still didn't worked

Comment: console the deviceIngo.getUserAgent()  and try to run it on real device.

Comment: log displays the proper result, I think google has disabled above kind of login